# How can I remove white spaces from an input?

Tags: java, input, whitespace

This is the input: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHDJI.png)

I want to get the last number but how? (1,2,6)

I tried this:

String line = scanner.nextLine();

String[] parts = line.split(" ");

int ProductCount =Integer.parseInt(parts[3].replaceAll(" ", ""));

Comment: Getting the last number in a String and removing white spaces from a String are completely different things. You should clarify which one of those 2 things it is you want.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS both work for what I want to do, I couldn't do both of them that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last number you can do it like this.

- `.*?` reluctantly grab the characters
- `(\\d+)$` - capture one or more digits at end of string.
- `$1` back reference to captured value (21 in this case)
- and convert to an int.

```
String s = "kssk sk k22 s 21";
int v = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+)$","$1"));
System.out.println(v);
```

prints

```
21
```

A somewhat better alternative might be to do the following **if** there is always a space before the last number.

- get the last index of a white space
- and starting with the next character, get the substring and convert to an integer.

```
int i = s.lastIndexOf(' '); // returns -1 if no space is found.
int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i+1));
```